# Restrict TextFinder to a specific range: TextFinder startFrom not starting from

Tags: google-apps-script, full-text-search

I'm trying to use TextFinder, but in my spreadsheet, I don't want to return the header row or column 1 in my results.  I see that TextFinder has a "startFrom" method that's supposed to let you define "The cell range after which the search should start" ... but I can't seem to make it work.

```
var tf=ss
       .createTextFinder(text)
       .useRegularExpression(true)
       .ignoreDiacritics(true)
       .startFrom(ss.getRange("B2"));
var all=tf.findAll();
```

What am I doing wrong?  I get results, they just still include matches from row 1 and column A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `ss` is spreadsheet, you're creating a text finder for the entire spreadsheet. `startFrom(range)` only says

> The cell range after which the search should start

If you use `getCurrentMatch()` or `findNext()` it'll return the next range matching your `text` criteria starting from that range(i.e., `Sheet1!B2`). If you want a `textFinder` specific to a range, then create the text finder on that range:

```
var tf = ss
    .getSheetByName('Sheet1')
    .getRange('B2:B')
    .createTextFinder(text)
```

Comment: sorry, I should've clarified that ss is my specific sheet

Comment: but that .getRange thing definitely was the trick... didn't think I could do a textFinder just on a range like that.    Thanks!