# TextFinder StartFrom() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to tackle a small line of code for some time now, with no luck.

I have a text finder, which I need to start from the 3rd column (C)

```
var textFinder = responses.createTextFinder(tdate); var search_row = textFinder.startFrom(3).findNext().getRow();
```

I've also tried

```
textFinder.startFrom('C').findNext().getRow()
```

and

```
textFinder.startFrom(1,3,responses.getLastRow()).findNext().getRow()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, all I need is to get the row number of tdate - searched in column 3

Comment: Well, Have you checked the official documentation? What argument "type"  does `startFrom` accept?

Answer (score 1):

[`startFrom(range)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#startFrom(Range)) accepts  [`range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) as the only argument. You can get a `range` from [`sheet` or `spreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

```
textFinder.startFrom(responses.getRange('C1')).findNext().getRow()
```

Note that search starts from "C1" , but not restricted to column C.

- [Related Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297327/)